# Avoid duplication of values in a SELECT query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, duplication

I have a table named `product` which contains two columns:

```
id  name
1   p1
2   p2
3   p1
4   p3
5   p4
```

I run the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM product;
```

As a result, PostgreSQL gives me the following output:

```
id  name
1   p1
2   p2
3   p1
4   p3
5   p4
```

I want to avoid duplication of values in the `name` field, so the desired output should look like this:

```
1   p1
2   p2
4   p3
5   p4
```

How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: `DISTINCT` selects all rows where *all* columns have distinct values. In your example, every combination of `id` and `name` is distinct, you get all rows.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL has a syntax to do this rather efficiently:

```
select   distinct on (name)
         id,
         name
from     product
order by name,
         id;
```

The order by name is required.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: you have to add `id` into `order by` to get desired result consistently

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get non-duplicated name list, use 'distinct name'

```
select distinct name from product;
```

and you can also add row number using row_number()

```
select row_number() over (order by name ) as id, name_list.name
from (select distinct  name from product) as name_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use the select distinct on() statement above. But if you would like to don't get duplicated data into your table you can add a UNIQUE constraint on your name column.